# If define an instance variable which type is the defining class self

Tags: swift, class, instance-variables

What will happen if I define a class like below code with Swift, the complier doesn't give any errors:

```
class Test {
    var test = Test()
}
```

Comment: Why should Compiler give an error. This kind of declaration is not wrong.

Comment: That's perfectly legal, instances of classes can hold references to other instances of the same class. Why would there be any issues/errors?

Comment: This is perfectly valid. Consider a linked list. The nodes in a linked list hold references to other nodes, just like your var test holds a reference to a second Test object.

Comment: The problem is an infinite recursive call to Test() which will cause a runtime error

Comment: You should atleast mention the reason you think the compiler should give an error.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing strange happens.

It is perfectly legal for a class to hold a reference to an instance of the same class (i.e.: liked lists, trees, etc.)